# Is there any solution to detect modified app using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, hash, sign

I am pretty much curious to know If there is any solution to detect whether the app is modified by the user or not? I am using flutter for development. Cause nowadays I can see people are trying to modify apk files according to their needs. So I am confused about the spike for reverse engineers. If you people can give me a good suggestion to detect the app is modified by that particular user.

I will be thankful if you give effort to find a better solution for this issue.